# Where to place this invariant?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm working on a side project to learn and apply DDD within the "Daily Deal' domain. In my purchasing context, i have an invariant where a user can only purchase 'x' amount of deals per deal.

so it seems wasteful for my deal aggregate to load all purchases from all users just to check and see how many times (if any) the user has purchased this deal. I see two ways i could go about this.

1. Put this logic within a domain service which would allow a pre-condition to already have been met when the Purchase method on the Deal aggregate is invoked.
2. My repository implementation could always populate the purchases collection of the deal for the purchasing user. hmm...not sure about this one.

any guidance would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take the second approach, but with one important change.  I would instead create a value object called PurchasedDeal, that consists of just a DealID and Quantity field.  The User aggregate could instead load a collection of this more lightweight purchase history object.  Performance should be good with this approach, since I'm guessing that the average user will only have a few dozen purchase records.

Also remember that with DDD, you can and probably should have different models per bounded context.  So you might design your User aggregate like this in the context of deals/purchasing. However, your User aggregate in another context would look different and not have a purchase history if it's not needed.

Comment: i like this approach. seems like a good compromise. so would you have the Purchase method on the deal accept the purchase history object or would you allow a domain service to ask the domain object if it "CanPurchase" passing in the purchase history and then calling the purchase method if satisfied. not sure i like this as it could be seen as violating "Tell Don't Ask"

Comment: Personally I would have the Purchase method accept the purchase history.  The deal object could also have a CanPurchase method if you need to verify the validity ahead of time.  As long as the deal object encapsulates all the logic involved, then I think you are fine.

Comment: @Marco Have you guys thought about concurrency and data staleness with this solution? Not only that, but if you put the `purchase` operation on `Deal`, it seems weird to me that the `User` aggregate is actually responsible for tracking the history of purchases. Why not simply put a `purchaseDeal` operation on the `User` aggregate? You could use the ISP and declare an interface such as `ICanPurchaseDeals` to better segregate responsibility.

Comment: @plalx by placing the purchaseDeal operation on the user aggregate now the user aggregate is responsible for enforcing the invariants, which seems strange to me. not sure by reversing this responsibility would we be gaining.

Comment: @Marco Well, not necessarily, `User` can double-dispatch to `Deal` if needed. The fact is that the operation should be invoked on the AR that will get modified, but more importantly the one that is actually maintaining the data necessary to enforce invariants. The role of an AR is to be a strong consistency boundary, therefore a transactional boundary. What's happening when a `Deal` is purchased (in terms of behavior)? Also think about what would happen if you receive 2 concurrent requests from the same user to purchase the same deal.The invariant will be unprotected with the wrong boundaries.

Comment: @plalx two concurrent requests from the same user would not matter as optimistic concurrency kicks in and one will be re-tried. going back to my original question the deal aggregate mains a collection of purchase entities so i have all that is needed. my question was more so on the style of loading the related entities for performing the invariant check.

Comment: @Marco Well if the `Deal` maintains that collection, won't you drawn in concurrency failures? I imagine the odds of 2 different users purchasing the same deal is very high. This will greatly reduce the scalability of your system, unless you implemented automatic conflict resolution and even then...

Comment: @plalx true the deal itself has high contention but in order to enforce the invariants with transactional consistency (not eventual) i don't see really a way around it. yes, automatic conflict resolution is handled via the messaging bus infrastructure and compensating actions are handled when say for example the deal has hit its max allowed purchases. i am open for other ideas.

Comment: @Marco Well, to give you some advices I would have to know what has to occur when a `Deal` is purchased? Which ARs will get modified transactionnaly/eventually? Is there new ARs/entities that gets created?

Comment: @plalx when a customer goes to purchase a deal a long-running transaction kicks off. it sends a message to the deal aggregate and receives a response of accepted or denied. when denied, customer is emailed (probably rare case) and the process is marked complete. when accepted, the process waits for the MinPurchasesReached event and now sends off for payment. once payment confirmed a voucher is created for the user. some invaraints: deal has a start and end date, min deals for the deal to be accepted and max purchases allowed. as well as # of allowed purchases per user. does this help?